# Resizable method in jquery has a strange behavior with big numbers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have the following examples that work in a strange way when you try to resize to the left the child.

Any idea of what can be wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  
  var $parent = $('div.parent');

  $parent.find('.child').resizable({
    handles:  'e, w'
  });
  
});
```

```css
@import url("//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/start/jquery-ui.min.css");

@left: 15000000px;

.wrapper{
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: 50px;
  left: 60px;
}

.parent {
      position: absolute;
      left: -15000000px;
      width: 1500000000px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: grey;
}

.child {
        position: absolute;
        left: 15000050px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
       <div class="child">

       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a problem in jQuery itself, the css function doesn't get the right value.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  
  var $parent = $('div.parent');
  var child = $parent.find('.child');

  child.css('left', Math.pow(15,15));

  console.log('from jQuery css get',child.css('left'));
  console.log('from javascript DOM',child[0].style.left);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
       <div class="child">

       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to your very odd use of `left: -15000000px` on the parent and `left: 15000050px` on the child. If you set `left: 50px` on the child *only*, then the resizing works fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var $parent = $('div.parent');

  $parent.find('.child').resizable({
    handles: 'e, w'
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/start/jquery-ui.min.css");
@left: 15000000px;
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: 50px;
  left: 60px;
}

.parent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1500000000px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's a way I cannot use - indeed it is strange in such an example, but I have a very long timeline and I need something like that, I just created a small script to show the problem